# How to navigate to cell by typing destination?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Suppose I'm at the cell A1 and I wish to move to the cell P234 simply by typing on the keyboard.

I know I can click on the box which displays the cell name and type the destination P234 there, but I'd like to be able to type the destination without having to use the mouse. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> you can enter the cell reference you wish to go to.

[image: Screenshot of the Excel GoTo box]